# what 's the difference between GetWindowThreadProcessID and using TIB to get thread id?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to get main thread id of one process, i see that there are 2 methods:

first is using threadID=GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,NULL) which hWnd is the handle of process we want from

Second is using

```
_asm
    {
        mov eax, fs:[18h]
        add eax, 36
        mov [lpThId], eax
    }

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pId);
    if(hProcess == NULL)
        return NULL;

    DWORD tId;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpThId, &tId, sizeof(tId), NULL) == FALSE)
```

So what's the difference ?

Comment: `GetWindowThreadProcessId` does not operate on a process handle. I think if you read the documentation for `GetWindowThreadProcessId` then you'll see how these two bits of code differ. The question you should have asked is *How can I get the main thread id of a process?*

Comment: @David: Windows processes do not have the concept of a _main thread_. Likewise Windows processes also do not have a _main window_. So the only question `GetWindowThreadProcessId` can answer is: Which thread owns a particular window and - optionally - which process owns this thread. SieuTruc should clearly specify what he is trying to solve. Both your and his question cannot be answered.

Comment: Among other things, you are assuming the mail thread still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves the identifier of the thread that **created the specified window** and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the window.

It has nothing to do with TIB. The difference is that these two are different identifiers, which might be equal by a coincidence.

Comment: So, for simple window application that , Are they often to have the same value ? because the thread crated window is also the main thread ? is it right ?

Comment: They match if your code is on the thread that created the window of interest. It does not have to be "main" thread.